# .toBlocking.first() vs .getValue() are different on an ReplaySubject?

Tags: rx-java

I have an `ReplaySubject<Boolean>`. I do the following:

1. `subject.call(true)`
2. `subject.call(false)`
3. `assert subject.getValue().equals(subject.toBlocking.first())` //throws exception

How can #3 possibly happen? Note, these three lines of code are called on the same thread.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @BharathMg I am asserting equality on the same subject

Comment: Your subject.getValue() should give you false. And your subject.toBlocking.first() should give you true. So assert will fail. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @BharathMg shouldn't to blocking first return the current state of the relay?

Comment: Nope it gives you first ever value emitted from the BlockingObservable.

Comment: Beware you are using ReplaySubject. So you get all the values when you do first() which actually just does take(1).single() which will take a first value which is `true` in your case.